# Match last occurrence only in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
/1.1/s/1/-/g
```

I am working on school assignment to reference implementation sed command. I get this string to match "/1/-/". I have experiment

```
$str =~ m{/[^/]*/[^/]*/}g;
```

but result is /1.1/s/. How can I get "/1/-/" only
Could somebody help me?

Comment: Add a `\z` t the end

Comment: Since matching is "greedy", you just need to tell the match to ignore other characters at the start: `m{.*/^/]*/[^/]*/}`.  Adding the `.*` at the beginning matches any leading flotsam, and only the last match will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```perl
/[^/]*/[^/]*/(?=[^/]*$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/mLZ1rs/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```perl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```